# Java Error Page in web.xml not for all requests

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, web

Is it possible to setup error-page but that should be triggered not for all URI's but for example with /custom-path, and for requests with URI's /main-path do not handle errors?

In web.xml i suppose it is only possible to match error page with certain Exception types.

The problem is we have one single war file inside which we have both rest api and html management UI. So if error comes from rest api, it should be rendered as it is and no error page should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by calling setStatus() on HttpServletResponse instead of throwing exceptions or calling sendError().

Example of my Spring MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{ean}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(@PathVariable("id" Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {

    // response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
}
```

This way my RESTful API controllers don't render error pages.